# Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for FormApp.TimeItem.createResponse. (line 117, file “Code”)

Tags: google-apps-script

I get this exception anytime my form item contains time

```
 case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
     return item.asTimeItem()
        .createResponse(item.asTimeItem().createResponse(1,1));
      break;
```

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createResponse()  Apparently it doesn't require any parameters.

Comment: Nope, it does actually.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are unnecessarily calling [TimeItem.createResponse(hour, minute)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/time-item#createResponse(Integer,Integer)) twice, and using the returned value from one of these invocations (that is, an [ItemResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response)) as a parameter when calling it again.

You should be providing two integers instead of an `ItemResponse`. Hence the error:

```
return item.asTimeItem().createResponse(item.asTimeItem().createResponse(1,1));
```

#### Solution:

Call this method just once, and provide the appropriate parameters:

```
case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
   return item.asTimeItem().createResponse(1,1);
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

If item in question is a TimeItem then there is no method `asTimeItem()` in the [TimeItem Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/time-item)

Perhaps try this:

```
 case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
  return item.createResponse(1,1);
  break;
```

Comment: `item` here most likely refers to [Interface Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item), not to `TimeItem`. Even though it's fair to say there's a certain degree of ambiguity.